# My Iframe Facebook Fan page doesn't show anything on Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, iframe

http://www.facebook.com/pages/DaTerra/103976239692670?sk=app_229668230415514

This above is my Facebook Page. I can't figure out why it doesn't show on Google Chrome.

Did anyone went trough this before? Are there any other browsers that can't see this page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this error message in Chrome:
SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

In your app settings make sure that you have the secure url filled out as well.
like this:[image]

if you do not have a SSL certificate on your site i suggest using hostfb.com for simple html pages. They offer secure hosting free.

Comment: Thanks for that. It makes sense.

I'm gonna give it a shot and hopefully not ending up having to pay money to Mark Zuckerberg.

The man knows how to make money apparently.